# How do I persist the gridlines for ticks that are not displayed? [Chart.js]

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Chart.js for charts for a website and have came across an issue I can't seem to be able to solve. I need to display the gridlines for every tick, even the ones that are not displayed due to the lack of room for the labels.

Every tick has a date label and as many of these should be displayed as possible, however when the chart is resized or if there is a lot of data, some ticks are removed due to the Chart.js "nice numbers algorithm". This behaviour is expected and okay, but what I still want to have is the gridlines associated with each of these ticks. Currently I am having an issue separating the two as gridlines will only be displayed when there is a displayed tick.

Does anyone have any idea how I can display the gridlines for every index along the x-axis, but with the tick labels still displayed according to the "nice numbers algorithm"?

Here are some screenshots of what I mean:

[This is what the graph should look like with full ticks and gridlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujijU.png)

[However if I resize the graph smaller, many of the ticks are hidden, and so are their corresponding gridlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkthN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to hide label and keep displaying gridlines. But you could keep all labels and gridlines by set `autoSkip` option off:

```
ticks: {
        autoSkip: false
       }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option as the labels overlap with pretty horrific results after resizing.